# Transcribing place of occupation (Coal Pit) and information about it

Tags: scotland, occupation, place-names, transcriptions, ayrshire

I am trying to determine the Coal Pit where Samuel Harris was stated to have been working on 13 Feb 1877 in Irvine.

I can make out:

> Samuel Harris
>
> Engineman at
>
> Bay? Coal Pit

[image]

I tried to google it (eg: [Ayrshire - Scottish Mining](http://www.scottishmining.co.uk/155.html)) but nothing stands out.

I see:

http://www.scottishmining.co.uk/Indexes/Abandoned1889.html

Comment: It looks more like *Ravenscroft Coal Pit*.  I think part of the 'J' from 'Janet' on the line below just happens to be touching the 'v' in 'Ravenscroft'.

Comment: @sempaiscuba It could be, but I can't see such a coal pit referred to anywhere in Ayrshire. I updated my question with a link to a list of pits in Scotland.

Comment: From the 1896 OS 25 inch map, the closest pit to Ravenscroft in Ayr is *Rankinston No. 3 coal-pit.  It may well be that this was known as the "Ravenscroft pit" in the 1870s.  I would try to find out whether the local archives have any resources relating to the history and development of that pit.

Comment: @sempaiscuba I will make some enquiries.